# Google does not observe the mimetype when importing docs

Tags: google-drive-api

If I use the google drive V3 create api to upload a file and provide a legitmate mime type (application/vnd.google-apps.drawing, or application/vnd.google-apps.sheet) google will either ignore my mime type and create a document , or give me an error.

For instance is should be possible to upload an ODT spreadsheet to a google sheet, but instead it makes it a Document.  There doesn't seem to be any way to gain insight into what sort of heuristics that are applied behind the curtain.

I tried to add this in a comment but it only allows a few chars.  So here is my latest understanding.

I addressed my failure to create a spreadsheet via the create method by creating the sheet without any content and then using the update method to add content, which works.  I believe that there are bugs in the create api.

I continue to have problems with the create/update api for drawings.  I cannot create any sort of drawing using jpeg or png as input.  Here is some sample code:

```
func GoogleComment(actContext activity.Context,
    log logger.Logger) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    srv, err := getSAService(actContext, log, true) //get a *drive.Service
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var filesResource drive.File
    filesResource.Name = "somename"
    filesResource.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing"
    filesResource.Description = "some description"
    filesCreateCall := srv.Files.Create(&filesResource)
    filesResource.Parents = strings.Split(parents, "parentfoldera,parentfolderb") //fileids in the real world

    var outputObj map[string]interface{}
    text, _ := getInputVar(input, TEXT, false)
    imageBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("some jpeg image file")
    filesCreateCall.Media(bytes.NewReader(imageBytes))
    filesResourceResult, err := filesCreateCall.Fields("*").Do()
    if err != nil {  
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("GoogledocsCreate failed to update file for reason: %s", err)
    }

}
```

This always returns the error:   Error 400: Bad Request, badRequest

I have read here: https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2010/10/google-drawings-support-added-to.html
That the importer for drawings only understands WMF files, which are windoze proprietary and of no use to me.
Thoughts?
wcn

I would like to be able to upload content via the api with a little more certainty about the kind of document that will be created.

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand ``file`` of ``upload a file`` in your question. If you are trying to upload the files with mimeTypes shown at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19 as Google Docs, you can do it. So when you provide your current script, I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: To convert a document, include `convert` with the Boolean value `true` in your call's optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your mime type should be that of the source document, *not* the target Google document. Thus, for example, an OpenOffice .ods spreadsheet would be "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet".

Comment: I've tried it both ways and can't get the desired behavior.  For instance, when using text/plain it will always make a Doc.  What if I wanted it to make a spreadsheet or presentation?

Comment: If you want spreadsheet, format your text as CSV and use "text/csv". Not too sure about a presentation.